# LicenseService changes itself from disabled to automatic and starts up service

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, service, windows-sbs

I have `Windows SBS 2003` which has `LicenseService (llssrv.exe)` in services running. As per [Microsoft recommendation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316631) I `disabled` this service and `stopped` it just to notice it's `Started` again and set to `Automatic` day later (I haven't checked when exactly it happens or after how long). Anyone had this problem? Any advices on how to disable it properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to disable that service in Windows Small Business Server 2003 (SBS) [per Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/824196). In some versions of SBS the server computer would STOP after a period of time with a SYSTEM_LICENSE_VIOLATION if you stopped that service. Be glad your box isn't doing that and leave the service alone.

Comment: It doesn't restart so it's good sign. But it's complaining about licenses running out soon and it's running out soon because I keep multiple service accounts for printers x 3, sql x 3, etc. And I noticed because of this when the limit is reached some people's mailboxes stop working in Exchange 2003. Glad you pointed it out.

Comment: Why are you keeping service accounts for printers?

Comment: Printers access shares on servers and put scan's per department. Depending on department different account has access somewhere else. Granted that I could theoretically use one account but I should have ability to be "secure" by using as many service accounts I need per security recommendations of Microsoft. Setting up Exchange, SQL etc properly requires lots of service accounts for everything. If there's more then one SQL instance it's even more.